# How to add data to List in MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I want to add an item to a `List` of `MutableLiveData` in `ViewModel`.

`List` is `read-only` because it was initialized with `listOf()`.

But in a specific case I want to add an item.

To do this, I used `toMutableList()` to `type cast`, but as a result of debugging, there was no change in the `List` of `LiveData`.

How can I apply data to a `List` of `LiveData`?

```
class WriteRoutineViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _items: MutableLiveData<List<RoutineModel>> = MutableLiveData(listOf())

    val items: LiveData<List<RoutineModel>> = _items

    fun addRoutine(workout: String) {
        val item = RoutineModel(workout, "TEST")
        _items.value?.toMutableList()?.add(item) // nothing change
    }
}
```

Comment: `_items.value = _items.value?.toMutableList()?.apply{ add(item) }` - take the current list, create a new mutable list, add your item and assign it to the value. Currently you were mutating the same `value` inside the `MutableLiveData` which would not trigger a new event to observers (it's just an observer pattern under the hood)

Comment: `_items.value?.let { _items.value = it + item }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`_items.value?.toMutableList()` creates a new list instance, so you're not adding elements to the list in the `LiveData`.

Even if you did manage to add elements to the actual list object in the `LiveData` (by using some dirty cast), it would probably not trigger a change event in the `LiveData`, so subscribers wouldn't be notified of the new value.

What you want is to actually assign a new list to the `MutableLiveData`:

```kotlin
_items.value = _items.value?.plus(item) ?: listOf(item)
```

(if the current list in the `LiveData` is null, a new list will be assigned with just the new item)